# Visual Studio 2017 Android Emulator: Debugging while simulating driving using gpx or kml

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, android-emulator

I want to debug my application while the gps location of the emulator is keep changing.

The problem occurs when I start the driving simulator.

I use google route planner and convert it into gpx file. Then I upload it into the emulators "extended controls -> Location -> Load GPX/KML -> Run".

When I run the simulator, the debugging process is immediately stopped. There is an error saying

> The Application is in break mode Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code).

How can I simulate gps changing (driving) while debugging my application?

Comment: Suggestion would be to open Android Device Monitor and reproduce the problem. Then look at the logs in the monitor and get detailed information on what's going on